# App Store Connect, cannot add localization because name is already being used (it is used by the same app in primary language)

Tags: localization, app-store-connect

I have successfully created a new app on App Store Connect, primary language is English, and app name is free and has been accepted.
I am adding localised versions (using the language popup menu on the top right).

When I save the page of the new language, this message appears:
"XXX Name couldn’t be saved because the app name you entered is already being used. If you have trademark rights to this name and would like it released for your use, submit a claim."

It appears as if Apple is forcing me to use a different name for each localisation, but I want the name to stay the same.

I searched extensively and noticed others have encountered this issue but none has been answered.

*** EDIT ***
For those going crazy with the same issue: App Store Connect checks for App Name only for the selected language. Even if you created successfully an app in the primary language and the name was available, if the same name is already registered in the new localization, it will not be accepted in the new language.

Answer (score 0):

App Store Connect checks for App Name only for the selected language. Even if you created successfully an app in the primary language and the name was available, if the same name is already registered in the new localization, it will not be accepted for the new language.

Apps with the same name, but registered on different languages of the App Store, can coexist.